# How to remove Approval process from a SharePoint list that was created using a template that included approval process

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

A SharePoint list was created using a travel template that contained an approval flow. We don't need the approval flow anymore and want to use Power Automate flow with a different process, bypassing the "embedded" approval process. Creating list from scratch would be best but the SharePoint list fields are already integrated with an access database and input forms so we want to find a way to use existing list without the embedded removal process.

**How can we remove the approval object/process from the SharePoint list?** The person who created the SharePoint list doesn't see it anywhere to be removed? All we see is the flow output and notification emails etc. (**Approval object was not manually added using Power-automate; it was part of the SharePoint template used to create the list, and we don't see it.**)